# How Schedule actions work when field value changes?

Tags: process-builder, formula-field, date-field

I read in salesforce support page that -> If you change the referenced field value and the schedule hasn’t been processed, Salesforce recalculates the schedule associated with the field.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled_processing.htm&type=0

**I have a process builder when a event is created, schedule action fires 1 day after a formula field (date type)**

**The formula looks up to a field 'Lead Date' [On Opportunity]**

When 'Lead date' was set to 29th Aug.
The formula had value 29th Aug and a schedule action was in the Queue.
After sometime the Lead Date was changed to 31st Aug, so now the Formula field had value as 31st August.

**Yet the schedule action fired on 29th August**

What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted contains the answer:

> For processes that start when a record is created, Salesforce never reevaluates the record with that process. Scheduled actions remain in the queue, even if the record no longer meets the associated criteria when the scheduled actions are executed.

Because your process builder runs when the event was created, Salesforce will not reevaluate even if your formula field changes.

You may want to change your functionality to a workflow. It appears that these recalculate upon date field change in all cases, not only if the time-based workflow action was not initiated by an insert. See here for more information:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&type=0